# python - using data from dictionary generated by yahoo_fin

Tags: python, dictionary, libraries, currency, stock

I'm new to python and my goal is to write some code for stock analysis. I've installed **yahoo_fin** and just started experimenting with using that. I've started with extracting live quotes using **get_live_price**
ie

```
>>> get_live_price('aapl')
126.12000274658203
```

I am working with stocks that are in US dollars as well as stocks in Canadian dollars, which brings me to the need to express them in a common currency. So I want to convert all USD stocks to CAD or vice versa. Of course before I can convert the currencies, I need to first identify the currency that one stock is listed in.
I have found that **yahoo_fin.stock_info** includes **get_quote_data** so for instance

```
>>> get_quote_data('aapl')
```

resulted in this **dictionary**

```
{'language': 'en-US', 'region': 'US', 'quoteType': 'EQUITY', 'quoteSourceName': 'Nasdaq Real Time Price', 'triggerable': True, 'currency': 'USD', 'epsTrailingTwelveMonths': 3.687, 'epsForward': 4.68, 'epsCurrentYear': 4.45, 'priceEpsCurrentYear': 28.476248, 'sharesOutstanding': 16788100096, 'bookValue': 3.936, 'fiftyDayAverage': 133.55576, 'fiftyDayAverageChange': -6.8364563, 'fiftyDayAverageChangePercent': -0.051188033, 'twoHundredDayAverage': 122.48235, 'twoHundredDayAverageChange': 4.236946, 'twoHundredDayAverageChangePercent': 0.034592297, 'marketCap': 2127376285696, 'forwardPE': 27.076775, 'priceToBook': 32.194942, 'sourceInterval': 15, 'exchangeDataDelayedBy': 0, 'tradeable': False, 'marketState': 'REGULAR', 'regularMarketChange': -3.1506958, 'regularMarketChangePercent': -2.4260383, 'regularMarketTime': 1614010862, 'regularMarketPrice': 126.7193, 'regularMarketDayHigh': 129.72, 'regularMarketDayRange': '125.6 - 129.72', 'regularMarketDayLow': 125.6, 'regularMarketVolume': 45892833, 'regularMarketPreviousClose': 129.87, 'bid': 126.36, 'ask': 126.3, 'bidSize': 8, 'askSize': 8, 'fullExchangeName': 'NasdaqGS', 'financialCurrency': 'USD', 'regularMarketOpen': 128.01, 'averageDailyVolume3Month': 104097755, 'averageDailyVolume10Day': 84604500, 'fiftyTwoWeekLowChange': 73.5668, 'fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent': 1.3840704, 'fiftyTwoWeekRange': '53.1525 - 145.09', 'fiftyTwoWeekHighChange': -18.370697, 'fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent': -0.12661588, 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': 53.1525, 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': 145.09, 'dividendDate': 1613001600, 'earningsTimestamp': 1611765000, 'earningsTimestampStart': 1619607540, 'earningsTimestampEnd': 1620043200, 'trailingAnnualDividendRate': 0.807, 'trailingPE': 34.369217, 'trailingAnnualDividendYield': 0.006213906, 'firstTradeDateMilliseconds': 345479400000, 'priceHint': 2, 'exchange': 'NMS', 'shortName': 'Apple Inc.', 'longName': 'Apple Inc.', 'messageBoardId': 'finmb_24937', 'exchangeTimezoneName': 'America/New_York', 'exchangeTimezoneShortName': 'EST', 'gmtOffSetMilliseconds': -18000000, 'market': 'us_market', 'esgPopulated': False, 'displayName': 'Apple', 'symbol': 'AAPL'}
```

I am not familiar with dictionaries, and I do not know how to work with this data, but early on in that long list of data, I see

> 'currency': 'USD'

so my question is, how can I take just the currency data, or any other data for that matter, from a dictionary like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so my question is, how can I take just the currency data, or any other
> data for that matter, from a dictionary like this.

A dictionary exists of key and value pairs. In your specific case, you could access the `'currency':'USD'` via:

```
data = {'language': 'en-US', 'region': 'US', 'quoteType': 'EQUITY', 'quoteSourceName': 'Nasdaq Real Time Price', 'triggerable': True, 'currency': 'USD', 'epsTrailingTwelveMonths': 3.687, 'epsForward': 4.68, 'epsCurrentYear': 4.45, 'priceEpsCurrentYear': 28.476248, 'sharesOutstanding': 16788100096, 'bookValue': 3.936, 'fiftyDayAverage': 133.55576, 'fiftyDayAverageChange': -6.8364563, 'fiftyDayAverageChangePercent': -0.051188033, 'twoHundredDayAverage': 122.48235, 'twoHundredDayAverageChange': 4.236946, 'twoHundredDayAverageChangePercent': 0.034592297, 'marketCap': 2127376285696, 'forwardPE': 27.076775, 'priceToBook': 32.194942, 'sourceInterval': 15, 'exchangeDataDelayedBy': 0, 'tradeable': False, 'marketState': 'REGULAR', 'regularMarketChange': -3.1506958, 'regularMarketChangePercent': -2.4260383, 'regularMarketTime': 1614010862, 'regularMarketPrice': 126.7193, 'regularMarketDayHigh': 129.72, 'regularMarketDayRange': '125.6 - 129.72', 'regularMarketDayLow': 125.6, 'regularMarketVolume': 45892833, 'regularMarketPreviousClose': 129.87, 'bid': 126.36, 'ask': 126.3, 'bidSize': 8, 'askSize': 8, 'fullExchangeName': 'NasdaqGS', 'financialCurrency': 'USD', 'regularMarketOpen': 128.01, 'averageDailyVolume3Month': 104097755, 'averageDailyVolume10Day': 84604500, 'fiftyTwoWeekLowChange': 73.5668, 'fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent': 1.3840704, 'fiftyTwoWeekRange': '53.1525 - 145.09', 'fiftyTwoWeekHighChange': -18.370697, 'fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent': -0.12661588, 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': 53.1525, 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': 145.09, 'dividendDate': 1613001600, 'earningsTimestamp': 1611765000, 'earningsTimestampStart': 1619607540, 'earningsTimestampEnd': 1620043200, 'trailingAnnualDividendRate': 0.807, 'trailingPE': 34.369217, 'trailingAnnualDividendYield': 0.006213906, 'firstTradeDateMilliseconds': 345479400000, 'priceHint': 2, 'exchange': 'NMS', 'shortName': 'Apple Inc.', 'longName': 'Apple Inc.', 'messageBoardId': 'finmb_24937', 'exchangeTimezoneName': 'America/New_York', 'exchangeTimezoneShortName': 'EST', 'gmtOffSetMilliseconds': -18000000, 'market': 'us_market', 'esgPopulated': False, 'displayName': 'Apple', 'symbol': 'AAPL'}
print(data['currency'])
```

Output would be `USD` as  you're accessing the value of the key `currency` from the dictionary `data`.

---

For **further reading** on dictionaries, I suggest:

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries
- https://realpython.com/python-dicts/